# d3 js pie chart is not showing even there is not error in web browser console. and SVG is getting append

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, d3.js, razor

I am using C# for programming the back end with MVC 4 design pattern. I have created one controller that binds data on which is stored in `viewdata` with controller. Here is the JSON that I stored in `viewdata["monthTrip"]` in the controller.

```
"[{\"label\":\"August-2017\",\"value\":\"35470\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"},{\"label\":\"December-2017\",\"value\":\"33598\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"},{\"label\":\"January-2018\",\"value\":\"22203\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"},{\"label\":\"July-2017\",\"value\":\"24633\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"},{\"label\":\"November-2017\",\"value\":\"41667\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"},{\"label\":\"October-2017\",\"value\":\"35546\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"},{\"label\":\"September-2017\",\"value\":\"31224\",\"color\":\"#582D92\"}]"
```

Here is the javascript code as a part of cshtml

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var pie = new d3pie("tripMonthsChart", {
                "size": {
                    "canvasHeight": 270,
                    "canvasWidth": 320,
                    "pieInnerRadius": "45%",
                    "pieOuterRadius": "65%"
                },
                "data": {
                    "sortOrder": "value-desc",
                    "content": JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.monthTrip)))
                },
                "labels": {
                    "inner": {
                        "format": "value"
                    },
                    "mainLabel": {
                        "fontSize": 16
                    },
                    "percentage": {
                        "color": "#ffffff",
                        "decimalPlaces": 0
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "color": "#000000",
                        "fontSize": 18
                    },
                    "lines": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "style": "straight"
                    },
                    "truncation": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                },
                "tooltips": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "type": "placeholder",
                    "string": "{label}: {value} ({percentage}%)",
                    "styles": {
                        "fontSize": 18
                    }
                },
                "effects": {
                    "pullOutSegmentOnClick": {
                        "speed": 400,
                        "size": 8
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you a `<div id="tripMonthsChart"></div>` somewhere in your HTML?

Comment: Or try it with a JSON without the \ and with `'` instead of `"` at the beginning and the end. Something like `'[{"label":"August-2017","value":"35470", ...`

Comment: @roland i have that div in which svg gets append but chart is not appearing. JSON.parse is working fine. still let me try to remove \ here.

Comment: @roland tried with removing \" with ' still chart is still not appearing but `not valid:  {label: "August-2017", value: "35470", color: "#FF0000"}` message in console is appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange to know this but its solved by parsing JSON`s value field as Number

`"[{\"label\":\"August-2017\",\"value\":\"35470\"},{\"label\":\"December-2017\",\"value\":\"33598\"},{\"label\":\"January-2018\",\"value\":\"22203\"},{\"label\":\"July-2017\",\"value\":\"24633\"},{\"label\":\"November-2017\",\"value\":\"41667\"},{\"label\":\"October-2017\",\"value\":\"35546\"},{\"label\":\"September-2017\",\"value\":\"31224\"}]"`

need to edited into

`[{"label":"August-2017","value":35470,"color":"#582D92"},{"label":"December-2017","value":33598,{\"label\":\"January-2018\","value":22203,{\"label\":\"July-2017\","value":24633,{\"label\":\"November-2017\","value":41667,{\"label\":\"October-2017\","value":35546},{\"label\":\"September-2017\","value":31224}]"`

value field of json must be without ' or " than only graph is getting display.